# How to obtain fully qualified domain name (or just domain name) in Erlang/Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Erlang has [inet.gethostname](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#gethostname-0) to obtain the hostname:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, hostname} = :inet.gethostname
{:ok, 'Michaels-MacBook-Pro'}
```

But how do you obtain the domain name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:net_adm.dns_hostname(:net_adm.localhost)
```

seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the most elegant solution, but this is the only thing I've found that works so far:

```
def fqdn do
  {fqdn, _exit_status} = System.cmd("hostname", ["-f"])
  String.trim(fqdn)
end
```